# CodeIgniter error solving

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am a new user of CodeIgniter. First I install CodeIgniter, then wrote the following code and try to run it with the help of my browser. I save the program in `htdocs/application/controllers/hello.php` but it shows the error:

> Warning: define() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in D:\xampp\htdocs\ci_intro\hello.php on line 2
>
> No direct script access is allowed.

What is the problem?

```
<?php 
if(!define('BASEPATH','')) exit('no direct script access allowed');
class Hello extends CI_Controller{
public function index()
{
    echo "this is my index function";
}
    public function one()
    {
       $this->load->view('one');
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Sorry,it gives the above warning

Comment: Please take the time to use the formatting tools in your questions so they are readable, like it is now. Also, add at least some of your question prior to your code - starting with code and no context can be a bit confusing for readers.

Answer (score 4):

It should be `defined` not `define`.

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
```